# Google Autocomplete Places API sessiontoken parameter

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-autocomplete

I am lost with the session token parameter in the webservice api.

Is it: sessionToken or sessiontoken?

I can't find the truth. If I see documentation it's sessionToken but in the postman api it's sessiontoken.

[image]

Then which one is the correct please?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the documentation you are referring to?  The Places API Web service shows [sessiontoken](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#sessiontoken)

Comment: Here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest.sessionToken

Comment: That is the JavaScript API.  Which API are you using?

Comment: Webservice api not js

Comment: You have this question tagged [google-maps-api-3]. That is the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. You are looking at the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web service api is sessiontoken
javasacript is sessionToken

Thanks,